# Get the user-selected timeframe when using the "timeframe=D" option

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am using the `timeframe="D"` option for a script. This instructs Pine to use the daily timeframe to process the data, no matter what timeframe the user selects from the chart menu.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to read the **user-selected** timeframe. I tried in three different ways, and none of it works, they all report the daily timeframe. Yes, by using the `timeframe="D"` option I instruct the script to do just that, but I still need a way to know whether the user selected a different timeframe from the button menu.

Here is the script if you would like to give it a try.

Alex

```
//@version=5
indicator("Timeframes", timeframe="D")

var tf = 0

// FIRST TRY
// -------------------
if (timeframe.isdaily)
    tf := 1
if (timeframe.isweekly)
    tf := 2
if (timeframe.ismonthly)
    tf := 3
plot (tf)

// SECOND TRY
// -------------------
if (timeframe.period == "D")
    tf := 1
if (timeframe.period == "W")
    tf := 2
if (timeframe.period == "M")
    tf := 3
plot (tf)

// THIRD TRY (the time difference between bars is the same for all timeframes: 86400000)
// -------------------
plot (time - time[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `timeframe="D"` in the `indicator()`, the `timeframe.period` will always be `D`. That's why you see no change. If you need to calculate everything in the `D` timeframe, you should not use a fixed timeframe in the `indicator()`, but rather use a [request.security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity) call to get the daily values to use in your calculations. The above link contains an example of such a request on the daily timeframe. When doing it like that, `timeframe.period` will contain the user-selected timeframe of the chart, while your calculations will be done on the daily timeframe.